# CompositionTarget.Rendering & DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatchertimer

Can CompositionTarget.Rendering & DispatcherTimer's not co-exist? I have a control that is updating by registering to CompositionTarget.Rendering and elsewhere I have DispatcherTimer. The timer was not firing at all, and after some trial and errors, it appears when I remove CompositionTarget.Rendering, the timers work again. Is there a limitation with having both of these? And if so, what's the reasoning behind it? If not, any ideas why that's the case in mine? My rendering is nothing intensive yet, so that's not the cause. Even if that is the case, the timers should still fire but at a much slower rate than I wanted it instead of entirely not firing. Thoughts?

Thanks